# Error while setting up RNN2 with react-native 0.59

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

ERROR:native-navigation' has variant 'reactNative51Debug' selected, but the module ''app'' depends on variant 'reactNative57Debug'.

I get the above error while setting RNN2 in android.
I am using react-native version 0.59.3.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and after going through several threads and answers I had to downgrade my RN from 0.59 to 0.57 to make it work. If downgrading is an option for you, you can do it like this:

- Open the file of your project named as package.json
- inside it you can find react-native": "0.56.4" replace this version with react-native": "0.55.4" or what ever the version you want
- Inside your project directory and run the command npm-install
- after installation check the version of react-native by running the command react-native --version and make sure that version is which you changed in package.json
- restart your project and you are ready to go